# How should multiple objects in a thread access a server connection object at the threads root scope?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, variables, global

I'm making an abstract swing gui for q/kdb+ data types that map objects from a q server onto widgets. I'm using the server connection api from the kx wiki to send and receive messages from the server.

At the moment, I only allow one single gui for each instance of the program but am about to start working on having multiple guis, each in a  separate thread, for different namespaces on the server. The way the current guis widgets communicate with the server is by referencing the connection object from the main class, which makes it a global variable and therefore not really OOP.

An example of an update method in one of the widget classes:

```
private void updateServer(){
    Main.gui.passMessage(this.data);
}
```

I want to know how each widget object in a GUI's thread could access a server connection variable on that thread, instead of having to reference a synchronised single global object on the main class.

This is really more of a theoretical question about inter object communication I guess, but it's just something I haven't been able to find any information about.

Note: I don't want to use a DOM since the q/kdb+'s api for jdbc is a bit buggy

Comment: Sounds like a typical producer-consumer scenario: Have a look at at the javadoc of the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: @Ralf I'll have a look, thanks! EDIT: so the producer class is one that has the server connection, and the consumers are the widgets? This might just be what I'm looking for...